# How to change the color of all text on webpage using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, colors

I am trying to make a button on my website that changes the background and text/font color.

This is what I have right now:

```html
some text<br>
<input type="button" value="Dark" onClick="document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black'; document.body.style.color = 'white';">
```

I got the background color to change but I can't seem to get the text/font color to change, would anyone be able to help?

Comment: it is working here. what is the problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

I added an id to the button and did `document.getElementById('button').style.color = 'white'`

Full Example: 
`<input type="button" value="Dark" id="button" onClick="document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black'; document.getElementById('button').style.color = 'white';">`

This changed the text to white for the button.

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/yns15r6k/

Answer (score -1):

Create a function to handle the click. Lets call it handleClick and put the statements for changing the color and background color inside. Then onClick={this.handleClick}.